# Individual TextBox calculation

Tags: android-layout, listview, dialog, onitemclicklistener

I need to be able to edit the value of TextBox such that if I enter a value less then 850 it gets subtracted from it and is stored in the text box.Thank you
[This is the output of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjY5L.png)

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private Adapter adap;
    private EditText dialogButton;
    private Context context =this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        List<Students> list = getListItemData();

        adap = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
        rv.setAdapter(adap);
        dialogButton = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_amount);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final android.app.AlertDialog.Builder inputAlert = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                inputAlert.setTitle("Title of the Input Box");
                inputAlert.setMessage("We need your name to proceed");
                final EditText userInput = new EditText(context);
                inputAlert.setView(userInput);
                inputAlert.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String userInputValue = userInput.getText().toString();
                        EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_amount);
                        et.setText(userInputValue);
                    }
                });
                inputAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = inputAlert.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }




    public List<Students> getListItemData(){
        List<Students> listItem = new ArrayList<Students>();
        listItem.add(new Students("Prashant Dhimal",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Prashanta",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Pratistha",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Prince",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Ranjan",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Rabi Tiwari",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Rajan ",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Rahul",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Rachana",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Ravi karki",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Raisha",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Rashmi",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Rinku",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Rajat",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Rabin",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Ramesh",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Ragbendra",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Subash Gautam",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Subash Gc",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Subash Parajuli",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Sudip bajgai",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Suman Thapa",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Suman Shrestha",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Saurav Man Pradhan",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Saurav Karn",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Shruti",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Swagat Gaire",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Swagat Ranjit",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Swikriti ",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Udin",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Ujwal",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Yunisha",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Sahan",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Samyukta",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Sanjay Koju",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Sanjay Thapa",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Srizan",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Ram",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Susovik",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Suraj",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Ujwal",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Sital",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Siddharth",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Sagar",850));
        listItem.add(new Students("Sudarshan",850));



        return listItem;

    }
}
```

Adapter.java

```
    public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Viewholder> {
    private List<Students> studentsList;
    private Context context;

    public Adapter(Context context, List<Students> studentsList){
        this.context=context;
        this.studentsList=studentsList;
    }
    @Override
    public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item,null);
        Viewholder hld = new Viewholder(layoutView);
        return hld;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Viewholder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(studentsList.get(position).getName());
        holder.amount.setText(Integer.toString(studentsList.get(position).getAmt()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.studentsList.size();
    }
}
```

Viewholder.java

```
    public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    public TextView name;
    public EditText amount;

    public Viewholder(View v) {
        super(v);
        name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Name);
        amount = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et_amount);


    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.zaraki.calculationapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

single_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Prashant Dhimal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/et_amount"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Name"
        android:hint="850"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```